# I get an error while installing Windows XP "could not find place for swap file"

Tags: windows-xp, boot, windows-installation, hiren

When installing Windows XP from MS-DOS (HBCD-HirenBootCD) i get the following message:

"An internal Setup error has occoured.
Could not find place for swap file."

I can't boot from CD/USB so i've copied the cd to the HDD (from HBCD)

Comment: How big is your HD and how is it partitioned. Is it formatted?
And is d: a second harddisk, or a second partition?

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are translating the message and what the message means is *Could not find space for swap file*.

It's some time since I installed XP, but I think it tries initially to create a swap file of a size related to your installed memory (eg twice the RAM size). The message, if I'm interpreting it correctly, means that you don't have enough free space on your install disc.

For example, if you have the maximum 4GB of RAM (for a 32-bit OS), you will need a file this size for hibernation (`hiberfil.sys`), plus an 8GB file for swap (`pagefile.sys`), meaning that you need at least 12GB more than what the installed files occupy, so I would suggest a target disc of 32GB or more.

If you are installing in a VM, it is easy to configure a larger virtual drive - you could also make it expandable. You can also easily reduce the VM's memory to reduce the swap/hibernation overhead.

If you are installing to a hard disc, then you need a bigger disc, or you have to remove or disable RAM modules.

Once the system has been installed and booted, you can change the swap file location and size (though not the hibernation file).

By the way, the rule of thumb that swap size is double RAM size is a very poor one: the swap space needed depends on the number and size of the programs you run, and will normally need to increase if the RAM size is reduced.

Comment: I'm installing on an old laptop, the available space is only 19GB, and the memory is 2GB RAM

Comment: i'm not installing a VM, but in that case it would be much easier

Comment: You might just squeeze it in if you use Hiren to format the drive as NTFS compressed: make sure you don't reformat during installation.

Answer (score 0):

this worked in the end:

- format drive c: (fat32)
- boot under freeDOS
- run setup (/i386/winnt.exe)
- when the setup ask, convert the drive to ntfs

PS: HBCD creates drives on that drive which corrupts the installation (also creates big swap files)